# perl script to remove next line with duplicate words

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

input:

```
DFF_2 : dff_0_2 port map(READY_c => READY_c, CT0 =>CT0);
\DFF_0\ : dff_0 port map(un1_CT1 => un1_CT1, CT2 =>CT2);
DFF_10 : dff_0_10 port map(MRVQN1 => MRVQN1, un1_CT2_1 =>GSMC_un1_CT2_1);
DFF_1 : dff_0_1 port map(un1_CT2_1 =>GSMC_un1_CT2_1);
DFF_1 : dff_0_1 port map(un1_CT2_1 =>un1_CT2_1);
```

expected output1:

```
DFF_2 : dff_0_2 port map(READY_c => READY_c, CT0 =>CT0);
\DFF_0\ : dff_0 port map(un1_CT1 => un1_CT1, CT2 =>CT2);
DFF_10 : dff_0_10 port map(MRVQN1 => MRVQN1, un1_CT2_1 =>GSMC_un1_CT2_1);
DFF_1 : dff_0_1 port map(un1_CT2_1 =>un1_CT2_1);
```

expected output2: (no need to be in order, but updated line should be resumed)

```
DFF_1 : dff_0_1 port map(un1_CT2_1 =>un1_CT2_1);    
DFF_10 : dff_0_10 port map(MRVQN1 => MRVQN1, un1_CT2_1 =>GSMC_un1_CT2_1);
\DFF_0\ : dff_0 port map(un1_CT1 => un1_CT1, CT2 =>CT2);    
DFF_2 : dff_0_2 port map(READY_c => READY_c, CT0 =>CT0);
```

I can't use duplicate line removal perl script for this situation as the string word8 is updated with new string word10. I tried like reverse the content and apply line with duplicate word to be removed.but, could not achieve it by my code.

```
open (IN, "<input.txt") or die;
open (OUT, ">output.txt") or die;
my @reverse = reverse <IN>;
foreach (@reverse){
print OUT "@reverse\n"; }
close (IN);
close (OUT);  

output:

DFF_1 : dff_0_1 port map(un1_CT2_1 =>un1_CT2_1);    
DFF_1 : dff_0_1 port map(un1_CT2_1 =>GSMC_un1_CT2_1);
DFF_10 : dff_0_10 port map(MRVQN1 => MRVQN1, un1_CT2_1 =>GSMC_un1_CT2_1);
\DFF_0\ : dff_0 port map(un1_CT1 => un1_CT1, CT2 =>CT2);    
DFF_2 : dff_0_2 port map(READY_c => READY_c, CT0 =>CT0);




open (IN1, "<output.txt") or die;
open (OUT1, ">output1.txt") or die;
while (<IN1>){
my $save = "$1" if /(.+)\s\:/;
next if /$save\s/;
print OUT1 $_;}
close (IN1);
close (OUT1;
```

But it is not generating the output file as expected. Kindly help me out.

Comment: it is reversed.. it is to specify that the output file is not required to be in order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hash for to do it.

While iterate the loop try to split the line by using the `:`, So split the line with pattern matching like this `^.+?\K\s:`

`^` for the beginning of the match

`+?` helps to avoid the greed of the `+`.

`\K` for keep the word from splitting.

Then store the two data in `$first` and `$second`. The create the hash key by `$first` values. It helps to remove the duplicate.  Then finally the uniq values is stored into the `%hash` then format the hash by using `grep`.

```
open my $fh,"<","one.txt";
my %hash;
while (<$fh>)
{   
    ($first,$second) = split(/^.+?\K\s:/);
    $hash{$first} = " : $second";

}

my @ar = grep{ $_ =$_.$hash{$_} }keys %hash;
print @ar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx:

```
((line\d+)\s*:.*\n)\2
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/kX7vB6/1)</kbd>

---

How it works:

```
(          # Capture line to be removed
  (line\d+)  # Capture Line Name / Number (Group #2)
  \s*        # Optional Whitespace
  :          # : (Colon)
  .*         # Line Data
  \n         # Newline Character at end of Line
)
\2           # Next line starts with this Line Name (stored in Group #2)
```

Comment: Actual code contains special characters in the line name and content.

Comment: @SumathiGokul Okay, then change the `line\d+` part to `.*?`?